# Reading formatted text using python

Tags: python, csv

I would like to use python read and write files of the following format:

```
#h -F, field1 field2 field3
a,b,c
d,e,f
# some comments
g,h,i
```

This file closely resembles a typical CSV, except for the following:

1. The header line starts with #h
2. The second element of the header line is a tag to denote the delimiter
3. The remaining elements of the header are field names (always separated by a single space)
4. Comment lines always start with # and can be scattered throughout the file

Is there any way I can use csv.DictReader() and csv.DictWriter() to read and write these files?

Comment: Have you tried subclassing the existing classes and adding the extra behaviour?

Comment: comment part only: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158868/python-skip-comment-lines-marked-with-in-csv-dictreader

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can parse the first line separately to find the delimiter and fieldnames:

```
    firstline = next(f).split()
    delimiter = firstline[1][-1]
    fields = firstline[2:]
```

Note that `csv.DictReader` can take any iterable as its first argument. So to skip the comments, you can wrap `f` in an iterator (`skip_comments`) which yields only non-comment lines:

```
import csv
def skip_comments(iterable):
    for line in iterable:
        if not line.startswith('#'):
            yield line

with open('data.csv','rb') as f:
    firstline = next(f).split()
    delimiter = firstline[1][-1]
    fields = firstline[2:]
    for line in csv.DictReader(skip_comments(f),
                               delimiter = delimiter, fieldnames = fields):
        print line
```

On the data you posted this yields

```
{'field2': 'b', 'field3': 'c', 'field1': 'a'}
{'field2': 'e', 'field3': 'f', 'field1': 'd'}
{'field2': 'h', 'field3': 'i', 'field1': 'g'}
```

---

To write a file in this format, you could use a `header` helper function:

```
def header(delimiter,fields):
    return '#h -F{d} {f}\n'.format(d = delimiter, f=' '.join(fields))

with open('data.csv', 'rb') as f:
    with open('output.csv', 'wb') as g:
        firstline = next(f).split()
        delimiter = firstline[1][-1]
        fields = firstline[2:]
        writer = csv.DictWriter(g, delimiter = delimiter, fieldnames = fields)
        g.write(header(delimiter,fields))
        for row in csv.DictReader(skip_comments(f),
                                   delimiter = delimiter, fieldnames = fields):
            writer.writerow(row)
            g.write('# comment\n')
```

Note that you can write to `output.csv` using `g.write` (for header or comment lines) or `writer.writerow` (for csv).

Comment: Nice.  Now suppose I want to write to a file using this quasi-CSV format (i.e. using the four peculiarities mentioned in the question).  How would I use csv.DictWriter to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Assume the input file is opened as `input`. First, read in the header:

```
header = input.readline()
```

Parse out the delimiter and field names and use that to construct a `DictReader`. Now, instead of `input`, feed the reader the expression

```
(ln for ln in input where ln[0] != '#')
```

to skip the comments.