# Adding metadata / identifier data to a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, filesystems

Is there a way to add a "tag" (add a unique metadata/identifier) to a CSV file without affecting the contents or ability to read/write the file?

I am using Python, but I don't think the language matters here.

Comment: You might want to look at this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158868/python-skip-comment-lines-marked-with-in-csv-dictreader

Comment: I'd vote for the creation of a whole new file format that weaves both together. Not sure how that would hit a lot of OS and tool infrastructures in a breaking way but if it could be done in a non-breaking way I'd definitely be an adopter. I've had many woes to CSV files not having metadata outside of maybe tucking it into the file name.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just add comment lines that you can parse later.

```
#Creator:JohnSmith
#Date:....
#Columns:id,username,...
1,JohnSmith
2, ..
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I don't think this will work as the file could be opened / saved / edited in other applications such as Excel, which will read the comment lines in as data.

Comment: add comment lines very end of columns (not easily visible when open in ms excel) may be.

Comment: What about C/C++ ? How to add for those?

Comment: @SaumyaSambitAcharya I'm not familiar with C/C++ parsers, but you can use the line comment they accept.

Answer (score 22):

This would be compliant with W3C embedded metadata format: 
http://www.w3.org/TR/tabular-data-model/#embedded-metadata

```
#publisher,W3C
#updated,2015-10-17T00:00:00Z
#name,sensor,temperature
#datatype,string,float
sensor,temperature
s-1,25.5
```

Answer (score 9):

In case you are not sure that all possible readers/writers of the file will be able to interpret (and preserve) comments, create the tag in a second file using some name convention that links them.  Example:

```
myCSVFile.csv
myCSVFile.csv.tag
```