# Python Dict from CSV IndexError

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I need to compare 2 CSV files and I am trying to use the @Martijn Pieters solution at [Python: Comparing two CSV files and searching for similar items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268929/python-comparing-two-csv-files-and-searching-for-similar-items) but I am running into an error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is the code I am using,

```
import csv
with open('filename.csv', 'rb') as a:
  indices = dict((r[2], i) for i, r in enumerate(csv.reader(a)))
  print indices
```

filename.csv has 10 columns and 2000 rows. I want to index column 3 that has hostnames and then match with hostnames in other .csv file

```
type,id,hostname,os,,,,
phy,123,server1,rhel5,,,,
vir,234,server2,rhel6,,,,
```

I am not sure why I am getting IndexError. Please help to fix the problem.

Comment: which is it, spaces or commas that separates your data, you had spaces a minute ago? Your code runs fine since you edited.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @PadraicCunningham I have commas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have empty lines at the start or end of your csv file.

I was able to reproduce this error with the following code:

```
import csv

with open('filename.csv', 'wb') as a:
    strng = """
type,id,hostname,os,,,,
phy,123,server1,rhel5,,,,
vir,234,server2,rhel6,,,,

"""
    a.write(strng)

with open('filename.csv', 'rb') as a:
    indices = dict((r[2], i) for i, r in enumerate(csv.reader(a)))
    print indices
```

However when I removed those blank lines, the code runs perfectly :

```
import csv

with open('filename.csv', 'wb') as a:
    strng = """type,id,hostname,os,,,,
phy,123,server1,rhel5,,,,
vir,234,server2,rhel6,,,,    
"""
    a.write(strng)

with open('filename.csv', 'rb') as a:
    indices = dict((r[2], i) for i, r in enumerate(csv.reader(a)))
    print indices
```

Refer to this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18891114/3244627) on how to skip blank lines in csv.

Comment: Thank you @rvraghav93! That was it, at the bottom of the file there are few lines with only one column. I removed those and it works fine now.