# Skip comments lines of different types in csv.Dictreader

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have several tab delimited files that I want to read into dicts using csvDictreader. Each file contains several comment lines starting with '#' or '\t' before the start of actual data. The number of comment lines varies between files. I've been trying the methods outlined in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158868/python-skip-comment-lines-marked-with-in-csv-dictreader) but cannot seem to get it working.

Here is my current code:

```
def load_database_snps(inputFile):
    '''This function takes a txt tab delimited input file (in house database) and returns a list of dictionaries for each variant'''
    idStore = [] #empty list for storing variant records                                                                                                                                                                         
    with open(inputFile, 'r+') as varin:
        idStoreDictgroup = csv.DictReader((row for row in  varin if row.startswith('hr', 1, 2)),delimiter='\t') #create a generator; dictionary per snp (row) in the file                                                        
        idStoreDictgroup.fieldnames = [field.strip() for field in idStoreDictgroup.fieldnames] #strip whitespace from field names                                                                                                
        print(type(idStoreDictgroup))
        for d in idStoreDictgroup: #iterate over dictionaries in varin_dictgroup                                                                                                                                                 
            print(d)
            idStore.append(d) #attach to var_list                                                                                                                                                                               
    return idStore
```

Here is an example of an input file:

```
## SM=Sample,AD=Total Allele Depth, DP=Total Depth
## het;;; and homo;;; are breakdowns of variant read counts per sample - chr1:10002921 T>G AD=34 het:4;11;7;12 (sum=34)


        Hetereozygous                                       Homozygous                                      
    Chr     Start      End            ref           |A|     |C|     |G|     |T|     HetCount        |A|     |C|     |G|     |T|     HomCount        TotalCount      SampleCount
    chr1    10001102        10001102        T       0       0       SM=1;AD=22;DP=38        0       1       0       0       0       0       0       1       138     het:22; homo:-  
    chr1    10002921        10002921        T       0       0       SM=4;AD=34;DP=63        0       4       0       0       0       0       0       4       138     het:4;11;7;12;  homo:-
```

The lines I want to read in all begin with 'Chr' or 'chr'. I think its not working because I need to iterate over it to reformat the field names using the generator which exhausts it before the rows can be read into the dictionaries.

The error message I get is:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "snp_freq_V1-1_export.py", line 99, in <module>
>     snp_check_wrapper(inputargs.snpstocheck, inputargs.snp_database_location)
>   File "snp_freq_V1-1_export.py", line 92, in snp_check_wrapper
>     snpDatabase = load_database_snps(databaseInputFile) #store database variants in snp_database (a dictionary)
>   File "snp_freq_V1-1_export.py", line 53, in load_database_snps
>     idStoreDictgroup.fieldnames = [field.strip() for field in idStoreDictgroup.fieldnames] #strip whitespace from field names
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
> ```

I have tried doing the inverse of my current code and explicitly excluding rows starting with '#' and '\t'. But this also didn't work and just gives me a blank dictionary.

Comment: Is there only one per file? eg... the above comments/headers won't be repeated more than once per file ?

Comment: Yes, so from the example file I want it to use the row Chr Start... as the header and all the subsequent rows as the values for my dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should be able to do is skip all the preceding lines *until* something with a `chr` starts, such as:

```
import csv
from itertools import dropwhile

with open('somefile') as fin:
    start = dropwhile(lambda L: not L.lower().lstrip().startswith('chr'), fin)
    for row in csv.DictReader(start, delimiter='\t'):
        # do something
```

Comment: That works nicely to avoid the unwanted lines. How can I strip the whitespace from my dictionary keys though?

Comment: True, have managed to fix it now. Thanks very much for your help! :)