# Filter() on DictReader

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, filter, iteration

I'm new to python and try to comprehend how I can use the filter function on an csv.DictReader to filter rows from an csv file. [filter()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#filter) can be used on an "iterable" and as far as I understand the [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html#reader-objects) fits this [definition](https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html#term-iterable).

However when I try

```
f = open('file1.csv', 'r')       
dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(f.read(1024))
f.seek(0)
reader = csv.DictReader(f, None, None, None, dialect)

filteredReader = filter(None, reader) #None will be replaced with my function
for i in filteredReader:
    print(i)
```

I get `TypeError: normcase() argument must be str or bytes, not 'DictReader'`.

Please note, that I don't want to filter on the filepointer ([e.g. here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158868/python-skip-comment-lines-marked-with-in-csv-dictreader)), but on parsed csv rows. Do you have an idea how to do that?

Comment: What is `filteredReader` here? What is the full traceback? When using  `dialect`, there is no need to pass in 3 `None` arguments, just use `csv.DictReader(f, dialect=dialect)` instead.

Comment: As for the exception you posted, it cannot be raised by the code you posted here; it looks as if you passed `reader` to the [`os.path.normcase()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html?highlight=normcase#os.path.normcase) or something. The `fr = filteredReader()` line is entirely a red herring here; you are not even using that object.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. My question is not valid, other pieces of code raised the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `DictReader()` can be used as an iterable, and can be used with `filter()` just fine.

The `filter()` function is passed each row (a dictionary) in turn and if the function returns `True` for that row it is passed on:

```
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> import csv
>>> demo = StringIO('''\
... foo,bar,baz
... 42,88,131
... 17,19,23
... ''')
>>> reader = csv.DictReader(demo)
>>> def only_answers(row):
...     return '42' in row.values()
... 
>>> for row in filter(only_answers, reader):
...     print(row)
... 
{'baz': '131', 'bar': '88', 'foo': '42'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter works as you expect with DictReader.

Suppose you have this csv file:

```
numeral, English, Spanish
1, one, uno
2, two, dos
3, three, tres
4, four, quatro
5, five, cinco
```

(Note the leading spaces in col 2 and 3)

And you just want the odd rows:

```
>>> with open('/tmp/nums.csv') as f:
...      print filter(lambda d: int(d['numeral'])%2, csv.DictReader(f))
[{' English': ' one', 'numeral': '1', ' Spanish': ' uno'}, {' English': ' three', 'numeral': '3', ' Spanish': ' tres'}, {' English': ' five', 'numeral': '5', ' Spanish': ' cinco'}]
```

Note that the leading spaces came though to our data. OK, try [csv.Sniffer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer) this way:

```
with open('/tmp/nums.csv') as f:
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(f.read(1024))
    f.seek(0)
    print filter(lambda d: int(d['numeral'])%2, csv.DictReader(f, dialect=dialect)) 
# [{'numeral': '1', 'Spanish': 'uno', 'English': 'one'}, {'numeral': '3', 'Spanish': 'tres', 'English': 'three'}, {'numeral': '5', 'Spanish': 'cinco', 'English': 'five'}]
```

OK, `sniffer` successfully found to use [skipinitialspaces](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.skipinitialspace) in the dialect.